# jQuery slider animation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, settimeout, fadeout

I am making a blog template and I have added a self-made jQuery slider on it which uses recursive setTimeout() for infinite slideshow iteration.

The images in the slideshow are side by side and the slideshow works in the following manner:

1. The first image fades out and is appended to the last position of its parent.
2. So the second image now becomes the first child and the same happens to it.
3. And the slideshow continues running in this way.

The problem is, sometimes the slideshow goes crazy and for multiple times, all the images fade out and fade in at the same time. Then after a few seconds, the slideshow starts acting normal again.

Please let me know where the bug is.

The **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shourovfoisal/guw4wd34/5/)**

```js
setTimeout(function run() {
  fade_out();
  setTimeout(run, 3000);
}, 3000);

// var first_child;
// setInterval(fade_out,3000);
// setInterval also causes the same problem

function fade_out() {
  first_child = $('.timeline-list li:first');
  first_child.fadeOut(1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.timeline-list').append(first_child);
    first_child.fadeIn();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-title {
  text-align: center;
  font: 120%;
  color: #D35400;
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D35400;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.timeline-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.timeline-list li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="timeline-container clearfix">
      <div class="timeline-title">My Timeline</div>
      <ul class="timeline-list clearfix">
        <li>Image 1</li>
        <li>Image 2</li>
        <li>Image 3</li>
        <li>Image 4</li>
        <li>Image 5</li>
        <li>Image 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Say Hello to my little Friend `requestAnimationFrame`**

`requestAnimationFrame` is your friend

**The benefits of requestAnimationFrame**

> 1. They are browser optimised, so they can operate in most cases at 60fps (aka the sweet spot for animation).
> 2. Animations taking place in inactive tabs are stopped. Meaning if a user navigates away from your tab and you have an animation, it
>      releases the stronghold it has on the CPU.
> 3. Because of the aforementioned performance and respect, battery life and page responsiveness are better on low-end devices and mobile
>      browsers.

If you have the urge to perform animations in Javascript, then you have probably used a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to achieve this. This is bad for a whole number of reasons, the biggest one being they will suck performance from your visitor's browser and flatten their little phone batteries.

The problem with these two functions is simple. They don't understand the subtleties of working with the browser and getting things to paint at the right time. They have no awareness of what is going on in the rest of the page. These qualities made them very inefficient when it came to powering animations because they often request a repaint/update that your browser simply isn't ready to do. You would often end up with skipped frames and other horrible side effects.

Read this [Article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_requestAnimationFrame.htm) and here for `requestAnimationFrame` [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
function fade_out() {
  first_child = $('.timeline-list li:first');
  first_child.fadeOut(1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.timeline-list').append(first_child);
    first_child.fadeIn();
    requestAnimationFrame(fade_out);
  }, 3000);
}
requestAnimationFrame(fade_out);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-title {
  text-align: center;
  font: 120%;
  color: #D35400;
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D35400;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.timeline-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.timeline-list li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="timeline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="timeline-container clearfix">
      <div class="timeline-title">My Timeline</div>
      <ul class="timeline-list clearfix">
        <li>Image 1</li>
        <li>Image 2</li>
        <li>Image 3</li>
        <li>Image 4</li>
        <li>Image 5</li>
        <li>Image 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: So requestAnimationFrame basically pauses the animation when the browser tab is not being used and it synchronizes very well with the browser.
And it is specially made for animations.

Thank you so much Omer! This is exactly what I needed. Saved my day.

Comment: no problem brother you can go through that article I linked in it has very good detail and description of how and when to use it. Do select the answer as correct one if it sorted out your problem, so others might also benefit who are facing the same problem. @ShourovFoisal

Comment: Okay Brother. Could you please explain one last thing? I actually couldn't understand the reason of using the requestFrameRate variable in your code. What does it do? @muhammad-omer-aslam

Comment: Sorry for late reply, as it is Sunday, that was used to ensure a delay of between 4ms and 16ms in order to more closely match 60fps which ensures a smoother movement, why it won't affect in your case because you are fading-in and fading-out the elements rather than **moving** them along, see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/XQpzU/4358/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=XQpzU) , you can remove the variable and just use delay in milliseconds and it will work in your case.hope i made this clear, you can come again if you have any questions. just updated the example.